# Yii2: Yii::$app->request->queryParams Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I am trying to create **ActiveDataProvider** using the Yii2 [docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/653/displaying-sorting-and-filtering-model-relations-on-a-gridview/), but I am keep getting this error:

```
Calling unknown method: app\models\UserKeysQuery::load()
```

Controller:

```
 public function actionIndex()
    {
        $searchModel  = new UserKeys();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel::find()->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

        return $this->render('index', [
            'searchModel'  => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);
    }
```

Model:

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;
use app\models\UserKeys;
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;

/**
 * This is the ActiveQuery class for [[Keys]].
 *
 * @see Keys
 */
class UserKeysQuery extends UsersQuery
{

   public function search($params)
   {
        $query = UserKeys::find();

        $query->joinWith(['user', 'licence']);

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
        ]);

        if (!($this->load($params) && $this->validate()))
            return $dataProvider;

        $query->andFilterWhere([
                'key' => Yii::$app->encrypter->encrypt($this->key)
            ]);

        return $dataProvider;
   }

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: May be i am not sure but `if (!($this->load($params) && $this->validate()))` will be `if (!(isset($params)) ||  !($this->validate()))`

Comment: Is UsersQuery visible to this class? It doesn't have it in it's use list

Comment: @Hiphop03199 - I have used wrong model :/. I now get different error (I will update question).

Comment: Can you update the question to indicate what the new error is? There aren't any foreach's in your code so it's kind of a guess where your error is

Answer (score 0):

You extend

```
 class UserKeysQuery extends UsersQuery
```

but you use

```
use app\models\UserKeys;
```

assigne the proper valued  UserKeys or UsersKeys